# Accessing a hidden field in a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

According to the following quote, I expect to see `overriden nullstackoverflow` instead of `overriden nullnull`. What point did I miss?

[**Hiding Fields**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass **hides the superclass's field**, even if their types are different.

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B("message is here");
    }

    protected int i = 13;
    public void print() { System.out.println("Hello"); }
    public A() { i = 13; print(); }
}

class B extends A {
    private String i = "stackoverflow";
    private String msg;
    public void print() { System.out.println("overriden " + msg + i); }
    public B(String msg) { super();  this.msg = msg; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What point did I miss?

The point that `print()` is being invoked by the `A` constructor, and that executes *before* the field initializer in `B` is invoked. See [JLS 15.9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4) for details of *exactly* how class instance creation expressions execute.

So yes, it's using the `B.i` variable, but that variable doesn't yet have the value of `stackoverflow`. If you were to remove the `print()` invocation from the constructor and just write `new B("message is here").print()` then you'd see "overriden nullstackoverflow".

Comment: I don't know why I did not try to debug step-by-step. That is to say, it was time to see your answers (: Thank you. Eid mubarak. The question seems easy but not. Actually `i` is declared but not initialized before calling `super()`, that is, it is the hidden value in the subtype, whose default value is `null`. Upon completion of `super()`, `i` is defined(=assigned)

Comment: @snr: I think it's clearer to say that the field initializer for `i` is executed after `super()`. (That's why I specifically used that terminology in the answer.)

Comment: yes, sir. It is initialized after super() but declared by default value before super(). That is why i can be recognized as hider by default value.

Comment: @snr: I don't really know what you mean by "recognized as hider" but the fact that a field is hidden is independent of when it's initialized. You can tell that you're using the hidden field by just writing `String x = i;` in a method, for example... that wouldn't compile if it was still referring to the `int` field.

Comment: I mean the value which is in subclass hides the value which is in super class. The subclass’ instance variable(=hider) is of default value which is null for String. It has null value when it is declared. It has user defined value when initialized after super() call is finished.

Comment: @snr: I wouldn't think about one *value* hiding another, but one *field* - that keeps you in line with how the spec describes things. At that point, there are two *entirely separate* things in your question: 1) field hiding; 2) field initialization. You would see exactly the same result if you used a different variable name in `B`, showing that your previous confusion really wasn't about field hiding, but about field initialization.

Comment: You can also tell that the subclass’s field has been used by the mere fact that reading the superclass’s ̀`int` field can never result in `null`. By the way, the result would be different if `B.i` was declared `final`.